# Minimum no. of changes required to convert one array to another

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview and couldn't think of any optimized solution, 
Given two arrays having the same length(n), print the minimum of changes required to change one array to another.
e.g. 
arr1 = {4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 7}, arr2 = {8, 2, 7, 5, 3, 5} where n = 6, output = 2 (as we can change all 4s to 5 in arr1 and 1 to 8)

My approach :

- Create two hashmaps and insert the value and its frequency.
- Remove similar elements from the hashmap, as they are already matched.
- From the remaining two hashmaps, remove all the values having the same frequencies and increment counter by one, the remaining frequencies will be the remaining changes required.

*Edits:*

- Sorry for not providing enough details, this question was asked in an online coding round.
- You are allowed to change a value to another value or you can replace all the occurrences of a value to some other value, like in the example above. So, say I can modify all 4 to 5 or modify one 4 to 5, other 4 to 8 and 1 to 5, but that will lead to changes = 3, which is not the minimum answer.

Comment: My first idea would be to see it as a Set problem. There are numbers shared between both sets and numbers unique to each Set. The smaller of the unique sets hints to how much needs to be tweaked. And if the range of values in those arrays is limited - you could use pod types like unit64_t as bitmasks and then maybe simple do some binary operations to determine those sets.

Comment: This question is not clear. Be specific about what "changes" are allowed, and what the required goal is. If you change the 4s into 5s then the 5s are not in the same places in both arrays; what does "change one array to another" mean?

Comment: @kaya3, Hey, I have added more details for the changes allowed, the index of values doesn't need to be same, just all values in array 1 should be present in array 2, hope that helps!

Comment: @kaya3 Even without the extra information, you could deduce the rules from the fact that they replaced multiple occurrences of the same number and counted it as 1 change.  This was which led me to the set approach in the first place.

Comment: @HenkHolterman We can replace all 1s in array 1 to 2 or change all 2s in array 2 to 1, and output will be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job interview questions tell as much about the applicant as they tell about the employer. So, it is situational, often on how to react to such a question. They hardly ever are fully specified. Some employers might want you to ask questions to fill in the gaps, others might want to see you exploit every gap in their specification to your advantage. Still others just grabbed the question from the internet and don't really know the answer themselves - or they have 1 answer only and expect to see just that. Risky business, in any case.

Here my first idea: See it as a set problem:

- A: Set of numbers both arrays have in common.
- B: Set of numbers unique to arr1.
- C: Set of numbers unique to arr2.

Then I would guess, that the size of the smaller set between B and C is the solution to the problem. Which might be right or not.

See code below. The sets B and C have the same size for the arrays given in the question. 
I leave it up to someone else to explain if the question is well formed in cases where that is not the case.

```cpp
static void SOQuestion()
{
    constexpr size_t ASIZE = 6;
    uint8_t arr1[ASIZE]{ 4,1,4,3,2,7 };
    uint8_t arr2[ASIZE]{ 8,2,7,5,3,5 };
    uint16_t a1ns = 0x0;
    uint16_t a2ns = 0x0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ASIZE; i++)
    {
        a1ns = a1ns | (0x1 << arr1[i]);
        a2ns = a2ns | (0x1 << arr2[i]);
    }
    uint16_t common = a1ns & a2ns;
    uint16_t unique1 = a1ns & (~common);
    uint16_t unique2 = a2ns & (~common);
    size_t unique1Size = 0;
    size_t unique2Size = 0;
    for (uint16_t mask = 0x8000; mask != 0x0; mask >>= 1)
    {
        unique1Size = (mask & unique1) != 0 ? unique1Size + 1 : unique1Size;
        unique2Size = (mask & unique2) != 0 ? unique2Size + 1 : unique2Size;
    }

    std::cout << "u1sz = " << unique1Size << std::endl
        << "u2sz = " << unique2Size << std::endl;
}
```

Not that it really matters, but this algorithm is O(N).